# Check Android's Internet Connection in a Background Thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I am trying to check if there is an active internet connection, and after searching, I found a working code answered by Levit:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27312494/2920212

This seems to work fine except sometimes, it causes a lag where it appears like the app is frozen. I know its because the isOnline function is not run in a background thread. I have searched but unable to implement the background thread properly. Please find below the code:

```
    public boolean isOnline() {

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {

        Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
        return (exitValue == 0);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
    private void ChecOnline() {
    class CheckURL extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {


        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return isOnline();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            String myresult = Boolean.toString(result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), myresult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    CheckURL ucc = new CheckURL();
    ucc.execute();
```

Nothing happens when ChecOnline(); is called.

Comment: Have you tried with AsyncTask?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I fear I may not have implemented it properly.

Comment: Ok, do you have any log messages from that? You can try using the debugger and putting break points within the AsyncTask class, and see what it's returning,  Btw, not a good idea to put an AsyncTask within a method.

Comment: My code does work. I learned one thing though: Not to put an AsyncTask within a method. Thank you!

Comment: Check this out this might do what u want http://stackoverflow.com/a/42229749/5610842

Answer (score 1):

Try it using AsyncTask

```
private class CheckOnlineStatus extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //This is a background thread, when it finishes executing will return the result from your function.
        Boolean isOnline = isOnline();
        return isOnline;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    //Here you will receive your result from doInBackground
    //This is on the UI Thread
    }
}
```

Then you will call

```
new CheckOnlineStatus().execute();
```

to execute your code

Comment: Thank you, my code does work, I'm not sure why it didnt in the first place.

Comment: Awesome, that's the most important