# checking internet connection for some time

Tags: java, android, connection, android-internet

I'm trying to make my app check if it is able to connect to the internet.

My research tells me that network-level connectivity doesn't necessarily mean you can access remote sites / services.  For example:

[Detect if Android device has Internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493517/detect-if-android-device-has-internet-connection)

I have tried the solutions in that Q&A, and they "sort of" work.  My problem is that `urlc.setConnectTimeout(50000)` (i.e. a 50 second timeout) doesn't seem to have any effect.  Instead, my application is reporting an error almost immediately.

I want my application to keep trying to connect for some time before reporting a failure.

Comment: You can make your request perform certain number of retrials if it fails with specific exception, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @elmorabea..it may work, but should not (setConnectTimeout(50000)) keep trying for the specified time?

Comment: No, connection time out, will allow this time (50 seconds) for a connection to be established, if a connection couldn't be established by then, it will throw a time out exception, but the timeout API doesn't promise any retrying, you need to do that

Comment: @elmorabea  let me make sure I get this clearly..
the device tries to connect within the (50 seconds) but not necessarily for the whole (seconds), unless a connection is establish, it throws the error..
right?

but if a connection is already established, after (50 seconds) is it terminated?

Comment: @OmarLabib - Is my edit to your question correct?  If not, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: Yes, basically you are telling your request object you have 50 seconds to connect, if you cannot connect in 50 second or less, please stop waiting and throw an exception.

Comment: @StephenC, even much better :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42229749/5610842

Check this answer let me know if you found it useful

Answer (score 0):

The Android system already does that for you. Instead of constantly polling the phone for the network state, register **BroadcastReceivers** for WiFi and network state changes and process the Intents sent by the system when the WiFi or network state changes.

You should make a **BroadcastReceiver** that will be triggered when the connectivity status has changed.

**NetworkChangeReceiver.java**

```
 public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
  {
   @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)
    {
    String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
    Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     }
```

**NetworkUtil.java**

```
    public class NetworkUtil
   {
 public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
  public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
 public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;
  public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) 
  {
   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
 if (null != activeNetwork) 
 {
 if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
   return TYPE_WIFI;
   if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
  return TYPE_MOBILE;
  }
   return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
}
 public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context)      
 { 
  int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
    String status = null;
   if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI)
  {
 status = "Wifi enabled";
 }
 else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) 
{
status = "Mobile data enabled";
}
   else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED)
    {
 status = "Not connected to Internet";
  }
    return status;
    }
    }
```

**Add Required Permission and Receiver in Androidmanifest.xml**

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation for your problem is that there are many possible reasons why your app may not be able to connect.  These include:

- Your app may not have permission to connect
- The user's device could be out of mobile data or wifi range
- The internet may have been disabled by the user
- You may be trying to connect to a host whose IP or DNS entry is incorrect
- The host or its home network may be temporarily offline
- The service may not be running on the host
- The service may be broken
- There could be a some other networking issue affecting connectivity.

The "problem" is that only some of these manifest as a connection timeout.  Others (e.g. incorrect DNS entries, local networking problems, service not running, etc) will typically result in a *different* symptom; e.g. a DNS lookup failure, a "Connection Refused", a "No route to network", etc.  These typically occur immediately, and the network stack does not attempt to retry.

As mentioned in the comment, the solution is to implement a retry loop.

- You need to discriminate the different kinds of failure ... based on the exception thrown.
- For "timeout" exceptions, don't retry.
- For exceptions that indicate a failure that won't recover (e.g. network permissions, no DNS entry, etc), retry is pointless.
- For others, implement your own timer and retry logic.

Yes ... it is a bit complicated to implement this.  And there are some traps.  For example, it is *unwise* to have the retry logic attempt to retry immediately or for too many repetitions, as these can behave as "denial of service" attacks on the remote service.